# Android Key Store using (between different apps)

Tags: android

Would appreciate any hint what I am missing in below code?

```
void addKeyToKeyStore() {                   
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date now = cal.getTime();
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
Date end = cal.getTime();
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
kpg.initialize(new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(getApplicationContext())
     .setAlias("MY_ALIAS")
     .setStartDate(now)
     .setEndDate(end)
     .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(1))
     .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=MY_ALIAS"))
     .build());
}

void ListTheKeys() {
 KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
 ks.load(null);
 final Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
 while(aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
   Log.d(TAG, "Key Alias = "+aliases.nextElement());
 }
 String tempstr= "Entry for MY_ALIAS is " + (ks.isKeyEntry(key)? "exist" : "not exist");
 Log.d(TAG, tempstr)
}
```

If same app calls `addKeyToKeyStore()` and then `ListTheKeys()` - the entry is exist. It also works if app restarted or phone rebooted.
However if app1 calls `addKeyToKeyStore()` but app2 then calls  `ListTheKeys()` - no entry that was added.
Have tried set same sharedUserID in `AndroidManifest`(s) - no effect.
I need to be able to access KeyStore from different apps.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I have figured out - a bit messed up with sharedUserID. If the sharedUserID is declared properly - everything works.
Issue can be closed.